# Does the maximum amount of open descriptors in a server include it's children?

Tags: networking, kernel, multiple-instances, concurrency, max-file-descriptors

I know that Linux limits the maximum amount of open descriptors, usually to 1024.
Now say I need to create a server which will handle more than 1024 users, 2000 for example, without tampering with the kernel.
This means I couldn't handle all of them by just keeping a descriptor open for each client and polling them *select()* since my kernel only supports 1024 hosts.

But let's say I want to create a concurrent server and spawn a child/thread for each connected client

1. Does a child share the parent's descriptor limit, in other words could I spawn 2000 children and handle each client separately?

2. Does a thread share parent's descriptor limit, could I create 2000 threads, each handling one connection?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, there is a system wide limit of the number of fds open: fs.file-max.  Also, a separate per process limit called nofile via the pam_limits module (ulimit).

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

[How do ulimit -n and /proc/sys/fs/file-max differ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122679/how-do-ulimit-n-and-proc-sys-fs-file-max-differ)

> Does a child share the parent's descriptor limit

The system total fs.file-max limit yes, the per process ulimit no.

> Now say I need to create a server which will handle more than 1024 users, 2000 for example, without tampering with the kernel.

In a file in `/etc/security/limits.d/` set nofile for the user running the server at least as many as needed, perhaps 4000.

In a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` set  fs.file-max to at least the total number of connections, plus some for other programs. Perhaps 200000.